# Formula for percentage value of row above if the accumulated sum of the percentage values doesn't exceed a base value

Tags: excel-formula

[Last column(s) should adapt(D6 & E6), so the sum doesn't exceed value of B2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIuxT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in B6 and copy across:

```
=IF(SUM($A$6:A$6)+(B4*B5)>=$B$2,$B$2-SUM($A$6:A$6),B4*B5)
```

[image]